# CakePHP. Default redirect to 404

Tags: cakephp

I create my first CakePHP application.

My app contains a fixed set of routes. I want redirect to 404 any request that not match to defined routes. I do not want these requests reach controller. I want to redirect its immediately at the Router level.

Comment: If you have access to the server, you can simply use vhost entries for your site and do a rewrite urls in the server itself.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it lack minimal research & code tried to fix the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you only want your fixed routes to be used first make sure you remove / comment the `require CAKE . 'Config' . DS . 'routes.php';` statement in your app's routes.php to prevent the default routes from being setup. Then with debug off (set debug = 0 in core.php) cake should automatically generate an error page with 404 status for urls not matching a route.